# How to give the checkbox a value for each data that called from database and how to post it

Tags: php, checkbox

I don't know if this can be done in php. I have an equipment list that is call from database. User can select any equipment that they want to borrow by selecting the checkbox. I have checkbox named 'list'. The question is how to put checkbox value and post the checkbox value?? because I want to save the selected item(checked) into database.

```
<?php

//include("connect.php");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE equip_name_desc='$search'");
$row = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if ($row >= 1){

    echo '<table border="1"><tr>';
    echo '<td align="center" width="40">NO</td>';
    echo '<td width="200">DESCRIPTION</td>';
    echo '<td width="120">SERIAL NUM.</td>';
    echo '<td width="120">REF. NUM.</td>';
    echo '<td width="120">PRICE</td>';
    echo '<td width="120">STATUS</td>';
    echo '<td width="80">BORROW</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    $index=1;

    while($a = mysql_fetch_array($sql))

    {

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td align="center">'.$index.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$a['equip_desc'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$a['equip_sn'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$a['equip_ref'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$a['equip_unit_price'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$a['equip_status'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'?><input type="checkbox" name="list" /><?php
        echo '</tr>';
        $index++;
    }

    echo '</table>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Be aware of SQL injection. Do not use `mysql_*`, but `PDO` or `mysqli` instead!You are not escaping `SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE equip_name_desc='$search'` so your vulnerable to SQL injection here. Further on, Y U NO WORK answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how you put the checkbox value

```
echo '<td>'?><input type="checkbox" name="list"  value="'.$a['your field'].'" />
```

to post the check box value
assign it to a variable

```
$variablename=$_POST['list']=="$a[0]" //take the values stored in the array
```

Comment: If I stored in array, that's mean I also can do limitation on selecting checkbox... right??

Answer (score 1):

Well, pretty weird thing, but ill try to understand. I suppose the serialnumber is the unique primary. So you could use that as a reference for all the items in the array:

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="list" value="$a[\'equip_sn\']></td>';
```